# How to prevent Vue from loading the data multiple times?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm currently practicing Vue with Vuex and the REST API architecture (with Django). I wanna retrieve the data from by database and store the data in my global state in order to access it throughout my Vue components. It works fine so far but there is one weird thing I do not understand.

When I start my application I have the homepage where currently nothing is displayed. I click on the menu item "Contacts" and the contacts component loads (router-view) (API GET call is executed) and displays the table of all the created contacts and shows it properly (source of truth is now my global state). I can edit, delete and view a contact.The contacts are now stored in the global state as well.

**The problem:** Everytime I load the contact component the mounted() lifecycle gets called (which makes sense) and loads the contacts from the API inside the state so the whole lists gets dupblicated over and over. I just want Vue to make a GET request only once and then access the state's data (where to contacts are stored now).

Another scenario is when I update a contact and click back to the contacts menu item the list contains the old contact and the updated one but when I refresh the page it is fine.

Thanks!

**MY CODE**

**state.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

import { apiService } from "../utils/api.service.js";

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    contacts: []
  },
  mutations: {
    initContacts_MU: (state, data) => {
      state.contacts.push(...data);
    },
    updateContact_MU: (state, data) => {
      let getContact = state.contacts.filter(contact => contact.id === data.id);
      let getContactIndex = state.contacts.indexOf(getContact);
      state.contacts.splice(getContactIndex, 1, data);
    },
    deleteContact_MU: (state, data) => {
      let getContact = state.contacts.filter(contact => contact.id === data.id);
      let getContactIndex = state.contacts.indexOf(getContact);
      state.contacts.splice(getContactIndex, 1);
    },
    createContact_MU: (state, data) => {
      state.contacts.unshift(data);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    initContacts_AC({ commit }) {
      let endpoint = "api/contacts/";
      apiService(endpoint).then(data => {
        commit("initContacts_MU", data);
      });
    },
    updateContact_AC({ commit }, contact) {
      let endpoint = "/api/contacts/" + contact.slug + "/";
      apiService(endpoint, "PUT", contact).then(contact => {
        commit("updateContact_MU", contact);
      });
    },
    deleteContact_AC({ commit }, contact) {
      let endpoint = "/api/contacts/" + contact.slug + "/";
      apiService(endpoint, "DELETE", contact).then(contact => {
        commit("deleteContact_MU", contact);
      });
    },
    createContact_AC({ commit }, contact) {
      let endpoint = "/api/contacts/";
      apiService(endpoint, "POST", contact).then(contact => {
        commit("createContact_MU", contact);
      });
    }
  },
  getters: {
    contacts: state => {
      return state.contacts;
    }
  }
});
```

**ContactList.vue**

```
<script>
import Contact from "../../components/Contacts/Contact.vue";

import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
   name: "ContactList",
   components: {
      Contact
   },
   computed: {
      ...mapGetters(["contacts"])
   },
   methods: {
      ...mapActions(["initContacts_AC"])
   },
   mounted() {
      this.initContacts_AC();
   }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You have any code to show?

Comment: Make your api call from parent component, and update your store. Now add these component which get removed and inserted conditionally by either passing prop or the availability of the required data

Comment: Sure, I edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check if there're contacts which are already retrieved from backend.

```
   computed: {
      ...mapGetters(["contacts"])
   },
   methods: {
      ...mapActions(["initContacts_AC"])
   },
   mounted() {
      if (this.contacts && this.contacts.length > 0) return; // already fetched.
      this.initContacts_AC();
   }
```

EDIT:

```
updateContact_MU: (state, data) => {
  const contactIndex = state.contacts.findIndex(contact => contact.id === data.id);
  if (contactIndex < 0) return; 
  state.contacts.splice(contactIndex, 1, data);
}
```

Comment: That worked and makes sense, thanks! Another question: Can I use created() instead of mounted() as well? Why should I choose the one over the other? 

When I update the contact it is still shown as a new one tillI reload it.

**ContactDetails.js**

`onSubmit() {
      this.updateContact_AC(this.contact);
    },`

Comment: In your case, you can also fetch data in `created`. but just you need to be careful that the `DOM` is not rendered yet at that time.

Comment: I have an issue with your solution. When I update a contact (I do it with Vue.set due to reactivity) and I go back to "Contacts" there is still the none-updated contact unless I reload the page. Do you have an idea how I could solve it?

Comment: Could you provide information about that issue on your question in details?

Comment: Yes sure! My "ContactList.vue" looks like your solution right now and it works! It loads the contacts only once. Now, I click on a contact (ContactDetails.vue) and I change i.e. the name. Then I click "Save" and the data was updated successfully (in global state as well as in the database via PUT request). Now, (still on the contact details page) I click on the "Contacts" menu item in order to get to the list. There, it shows me the not updated name of the contact even though it is updated. If I reload the page (F5) it shows me the correct name.

Comment: Can you observe if `contacts` is changed in `updateContact_MU`?

Comment: @Juan I updated my answer, pay attention to edited section.

Comment: In the dev tools under "Vuex" there is my state array with 6 objects (0 - 5).The obj I update is number 5. When I click "Save" it does not get overwritten but Vue creates "-1: Object" inside the state (not even in state.contacts). Hmm

Comment: Maybe, you made a mistake in `updateContact_MU` function. return value of `filter` is array but not an item.

Comment: Your `updateContact_MU` version works fine. I thought I cannot edit an array in Vue because Vue cannot handle the reactivity. Therefore it provides `Vue.set`. Could you please explain? Thanks Antonio!

Comment: You need to use `Vue.set` or `this.$set` when you want to add a new property in object. If you try just like `obj.newKey = 'newValue'` than vue will not notice that change.

Comment: Thank you so much Antonio! I do appreciate your help :-)